# Find $\frac{1}{x-y+z}$ from given fraction equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, fractions

$$\begin{align}
\frac{3}{x}\,-\,\frac{4}{y}\,+\,\frac{2}{z}\quad&=\quad3\\
\frac{2}{x}\,-\,\frac{8}{y}\,-\,\frac{1}{z}\quad&=\,-\,8\\
\frac{4}{x}\,-\,\frac{6}{y}\,-\,\frac{3}{z}\quad&=\quad1\\
\frac{1}{x-y+z}\quad&=\quad?
\end{align}$$
I tried to find solution by equaling $\frac{1}{x}=a, \frac{1}{y}=b\,$ and $\frac{1}{z}=c\,.$ However, $b=\frac{149}{86}\,$ and $c=\frac{14}{43}$ which led me to ugly solution or no intended correct solution at all. How to find solution to the above-shown fraction equation?
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Seems like an appropriate method; of course, an ugly problem may have an ugly solution...

Comment: Those $b,c$ look right. `led me to ugly solution` Do you have a reason to expect a pretty solution?

Comment: @dxiv The answer choices for this question leads me to think that way. a)2/25  b)30/31 c)31/30 d)19/2 e)25/2

Comment: @garakchy There is probably a typo somewhere. Checking with WA [`1 / (1/a-1/b+1/c) where 3a-4b+2c=3, 2a-8b-c=-8, 4a-6b-3c=1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2F+(1%2Fa-1%2Fb%2B1%2Fc)+where+3a-4b%2B2c%3D3,+2a-8b-c%3D-8,+4a-6b-3c%3D1) gives $5662/15953$ which doesn't match any of those choices.

Comment: @dxiv perhaps you are right. Here is image of the question: https://vgy.me/bvttya.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go on, go on…
$$x=\frac{43}{133}\qquad y=\frac{86}{149}\qquad z=\frac{43}{14}$$
$$\frac1{x-y+z}=\frac{5662}{15953}=0.3549\dots$$
Beauty is not a requirement of mathematical problems – especially in applied problems, and even in pure problems.

Comment: thanks. The answer choices to this question looks different from your or my solution. Answer choices are a)2/25 b)30/31 c)31/30 d)19/2 e)25/2. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @garakchy. So, we may suppose one more typo in a textbook !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The open question remains what is the minimal amount of changes/corrections to the posted equations such that one of the book answers works ;-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici maybe. Here is image: https://vgy.me/bvttya.jpg

Comment: @dxiv. I tried ... in vain to change the rhs's !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Same here. A little code would probably sort it out, but it's getting late in my timezone ;-)